# IIS Server times out when accessed from different device

Tags: iis

I'm trying to run an API on a local IIS Server. I have 2 servers currently running, 1 nodejs app, which runs via Serve, and 1 API via IIS. However when I try to access both the servers via my phone, I am able to access the nodeJS application, however once I try to access the API, I get a timeout.

> This site can't be reached, **my ip** tok too long to respond. Try: checking the connection ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT

When I try to access both servers from my desktop, using exactly the same IP adress, they somehow both manage to work.

I'm really new to IIS, so I'm not suprised if this might be a silly question, but can someone help me out?

Comment: Please check the IIS logs to see if any errors or warnings are logged. If your API and Node.js application are hosted on different domains (for example, different subdomains or different ports), make sure you have properly configured Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS) to allow request.

Comment: The problem isn't necessarilly the connection between the two applications. It is more that the API Can't be reached. CORS settings on my API have been set that every origin, can get to every method, so this shouldn't be the problem...

Comment: Have you checked the IIS server logs? Are there any related error messages? IIS logs are located at %SystemDrive%\inetpub\logs\LogFiles.

Comment: As far as I can see, there aren't any errors related to this problem. I see requests being done from 2 different IP-adresses (which is correct), however I cant get any returning info from my phone

Comment: If you are trying to access the API from a different network, you may need to set up port forwarding on your router to forward incoming requests on a specified port to the computer running your local IIS server.